# How to filter tags in Antd Table with React?

Tags: reactjs, tags, antd

```
 {
title: 'Tags',
key: 'tags',
dataIndex: 'tags',
render: (_, { tags }) => (
  <>
    {tags.map((tag) => {
      let color = tag.length > 5 ? 'geekblue' : 'green';
      if (tag === 'loser') {
        color = 'volcano';
      }
      return (
        <Tag color={color} key={tag}>
          {tag.toUpperCase()}
        </Tag>
      );
    })}
  </>
),
```

},

```
const App = () => <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />;
export default App;
```

I want to add a filter for tags and display only the rows for which the tags have been filtered. Appreciate any help. Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this

```js
{
    title: 'Tag',
    key: 'tags',
    dataIndex: 'tags',
    filters: [
          {
            text: 'NICE',
            value: 'nice',
          },
          {
            text: 'DEVELOPER',
            value: 'developer',
          },
          {
            text: 'LOSER',
            value: 'loser',
          },
          {
            text: 'COOL',
            value: 'cool',
          },
          {
            text: 'TEACHER',
            value: 'teacher',
          },
        ],
    onFilter: (value: string | boolean | React.Key, record: DataType) => {
          if (typeof value === 'string') {
            return record.tags.some((tag) => tag === value);
          }
          return false;
        },
    filterSearch: true,
}
```